# __builtin_unreachable with floats in GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have the following code, which I am compiling using gcc.

```
float add(float a, float b) {
    float sum = a + b;
    if (sum != 0) __builtin_unreachable();
    return sum;
}
```

When I am using `-O3` I get the [following assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/q6hq8T).

```
add:
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        ret
```

But with `-Ofast` I get the [following](https://godbolt.org/z/WxMo9W).

```
add:
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        ret
```

Looks like compiler does understand assume that function is expected to return 0. What does prevent GCC to return 0 as in the second example without `-Ofast`?

Comment: Negative zero? -

Comment: @user202729 lol. you are right. It works for 1. Thanks.

Comment: Although I feel that unreachable-based value optimizations are not very well-supported (because in most practical programs you can't get too much from that?).

Comment: @user202729 Maybe. I was just curious why it was like that. The reason was simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> `-fno-signed-zeros`
> Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic that ignore the signedness of zero. IEEE arithmetic specifies the behavior of distinct +0.0 and -0.0 values, which then prohibits simplification of expressions such as x+0.0 or 0.0*x (even with -ffinite-math-only). This option implies that the sign of a zero result isn’t significant.
>
> The default is -fsigned-zeros.

`-Ofast` includes this optimization option, while `-O3` doesn't.

Without this option, the function is required to return the exact value of signed zero of the addition result, so the compiler simply perform the addition.

If the `0` is changed to some other value such as `1` or `1.2f` or `1.5`, then the compiler will optimize without `-ffast-math`.

Remark: if the value is changed to `1.2` (so the comparison is the same as `static_cast<double>(sum)!=1.2`, as required by the standard) then the compiler will keep the addition, although the `__builtin_unreachable()` will always be executed because there's no `float` value exactly equal to `1.2` when converted to double.